# creating a metadata driven pipeline - parameterizing a source file

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have CSV files that are placed in various folders on a blob storage container.
These files will map to a table in a database, and we will use ADF to copy the data to the database.

The aim is to have the pipeline metadata-driven. We have a file that contains JSON with details of each source file and sink table.

```
[
{
    "sourceContainer":"container1",
    "sourceFolder":"folder1",
    "sourceFile":"datafile.csv",
    "sinkTable":"staging1"
},
{
    "sourceContainer":"container1",
    "sourceFolder":"folder2",
    "sourceFile":"datafile2.csv",
    "sinkTable":"staging2"
}

]
```

A for each will look through these values, place them in variables and use them to load the appropriate table from the appropriate CSV.

The issue is, for a CSV source dataset, I cannot parameterize the source dataset with user variables (fields marked with a red x in the below screenshot).
[image]

Would appreciate advice on how to tackle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature is definitely supported, so I'm not sure what you mean by "cannot parameterize". Here is an example of defining the parameters:

[image]

And here is an example of referencing them:

[image]

I recommend you use the "Add dynamic content" link and the expression builder to get the correct reference.

If you are having some other issue, please describe it in more detail.